# If a column has duplicates, then how can I set other column values corresponding to the duplicate values same as well? (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I apologize in advance, I don't know how to frame this question properly.

Say we have a Dataframe df,

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| pen | cat | pizza |
| apple | dog | taco |
| pineapple | mouse | sandwich |
| pen | horse | pasta |
| apple | bird | biryani |

I want it to change as,

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| pen | cat | pizza |
| apple | dog | taco |
| pineapple | mouse | sandwich |
| pen | cat | pizza |
| apple | dog | taco |

I'm using this logic to do so,

```
index_dict = dict(df['A'].value_counts())   
temp_index_lst = [key for (key, val) in index_dict.items() if val != 1]
index_lst = []
for index_num in temp_index_lst:
    index_lst.append(list(df.index[df['A'] == index_num]))

for i in range(len(index_lst)):
    b_value = df.loc[index_lst[i][0], 'B']
    c_value = df.loc[index_lst[i][0], 'C']
    
    for j in range(1, len(index_lst[i])):
        df.loc[index_lst[i][j], 'B'] = b_value
        df.loc[index_lst[i][j], 'C'] = c_value
```

This works fine, but I was wondering if there is a pandas method or a better way to do this (in terms of performance)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us do `groupby` + `transform` to broadcast `first` value across each group

```
df.assign(**df.groupby('A').transform('first'))
```

---

```
           A      B         C
0        pen    cat     pizza
1      apple    dog      taco
2  pineapple  mouse  sandwich
3        pen    cat     pizza
4      apple    dog      taco
```